SvelteKit dynamic routing always 404 Not Found
I have a SvetleKit project where I want to add dynamic routes. It is my first big project where I use SvelteKit (it's way better than React ;). Suppose I have a page on which a lot of objects are displayed in an overview and I want to add a detailed view of each individual object. For the summary I created a /src/routes/overview folder with a +page.svelte for the summary of all objects. For the detailed view, I have made a folder with square brackets around an ID and a +page.svelte, i.e. /src/routes/overview/[objectId]/+page.svelte. But no matter what I do, whenever I navigate to a dynamic route, the content of the +page.svelte in the [objectId] folder is not displayed on the page, but 404 NotFound. I didn't put anything dynamic in the +page.svelte for testing purposes, only static "HTML". There are no error logs, neither in the development console nor in the browser, except the 404 not found
I already tried all the standard tips - deleting node_modules and reinstalling, deleting .svelte-kit and restarting, let the project build and run with the preview instead of just the development mode, used the node-adapter instead of the auto-adapter, tried to rename the folder for the dynamic ID, but nothing worked (I'm desperate). I already had the problem of 404 Not Found pages with some statically named folders, but there the problem was gone after I deleted the .svelte-kit folder once and restarted it.
I only use the server component of SvelteKit for the benefits of SSR, the API for the project itself is a completely different project (ASP.NET Core), so it is not requests to the API that are not found, the route itself is not recognized.
Ther is nothing special in my Svelte or Vite config:
Vite config
import fs from 'fs';
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    server: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync('development.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('development.cert')
        }
    }
});

The svelte.config.js is completely unedited.
I'm using SvelteKit in version 2.5.10

Just did a fresh install using the exact structure you laid out in your post, and everything is working fine. Same SvelteKit version as the one you're using (2.5.10). Maybe try a completely fresh install just to validate. Make sure you choose the empty skeleton, then only add overview and overview/[objectId] directories under routes, and a +page.svelte file in both of these directories, with just a single <p>Overview</p> tag in the first and <p>Detail</p> in the second. Start the dev server then navigate to /overview and /overview/test and both should render.

Which URL do you use when you get 404?

I have now also created a new project and checked whether it works there - it does. I'll probably transfer all the code from the "broken" project, as reinstalling the dependencies (node_modules) or deleting the cache won't help. I've no idea what causes the error.
An example of an URL that I could use for a 404 would be /overview/1 or /overview/anything.

I probably found the issue: There is another, static route in the same folder as the dynamic one. They likely conflict and the static route wins.
